# FontAwesome icons not displaying

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm creating a simple sidebar navigation which will soon turn into an admin area. I'm trying to use css classes to display my icons. Here is the code. Can you spot the problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navigation.css">
```

```
  <li title="home"><a href="#" class="menu-button home">menu</a></li>

  <li title="search"><a href="#" class="search">search</a></li>
  <li title="pencil"><a href="#" class="pencil">pencil</a></li>
  <li title="about"><a href="#" class="active about">about</a></li>
  <li title="archive"><a href="#" class="archive">archive</a></li>
  <li title="contact"><a href="#" class="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu-bar">
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-button">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

That's the end of my HTML, now here is my CSS.

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.menu li a:before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
speak: none;
text-indent: 0em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 1.4em;
}
.menu li a.search:before {
content: "\f002";
}
.menu li a.archive:before {
content: "\f187";
}
.menu li a.pencil:before {
content: "\f040";
}
.menu li a.contact:before {
content: "\f003";
}
.menu li a.about:before {
content: "\f007";
}
.menu li a.home:before {
content: "\f039";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to slightly restructure your HTML to add `<i class="fa"></i>` to the start of each of your anchor tags. You then need to add the FontAwesome declaration to this new `i` element.

**HTML:**

```
<li title="search">
     <a href="#" class="search">
          <i class="fa"></i> 
          search
     </a>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
li a i:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

li a.search i:before {
    content:"\f002";
}
```

This was happening because the `i` element must first exist with the class of `fa` since FontAwesome applies a few styles to that first. So if this is added to the inside of your anchor tags, using `:before` will work perfectly fine.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw52R/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.... now to figure out why Google Chrome won't display my icons. -_-

Comment: Chrome seems to be displaying them perfectly in the example I posted. Remember, if it helped you, don't forget to up-vote and accept it as the answer so others can see if they come across the same problem :)

Comment: Ah yes, brand new to stackoverflow. Once I have a little more rep around this neck of the woods I will definitely upvote it! :)